# adding npm module to Tabris results in a failed build with cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, build.gradle, pouchdb, tabris

Being rather new to mobile app development i'm looking at Apache Cordova paired with Tabris.

Tabris requires a particular installation procedure, this creates a ./node_modules sub-folder under the regular ./www folder of a typical cordova project. Build cordova here is not a problem.

After adding 'npm install pouchdb' to ./www/node_modules now the cordova build fails again and again. I don't see what else changed but the addition of pouchdb. Strangely while pouchdb is reported to be just 46KB after installation many more modules were added and it now weighs in at 55MB. I suspect the many extra modules pose an issue.

I suspect i may need to tweak gradle but i'm most clueless where to start.

please advise

--- below the output indicating build failure
.... many lines of output preced
:processDebugManifest
:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/opt/android-sdk-update-manager/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

<<< this is supposedly output from gradle >>>
* Try: 
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Total time: 13.708 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: /usr/sources/mobile/.../platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/usr/sources/mobile/.../platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true

... replace path for anonymisation
<<< is my own inserted line >>>

Answer (score 2):

First off: are you using **Tabris** or **Tabris.js**?  The former is a Java framework and is not compatible with Cordova.  The latter is, but if you're trying to use Tabris.js as a slave to Cordova (i.e. using the Cordova build command) that's not going to work.  Instead I suggest you convert your project structure [Tabris.js's style](https://tabrisjs.com/documentation/latest/build) and then run the build there.  If you still encounter errors when after converting your structure and building with Tabris.js, post the *full* build log in the [Tabris.js issue tracker](https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-js/issues).

Comment: Hi, sorry, yes i'm working with TabrisJS and have installed it inside Corova.    
I've found pouchdb has a .js version for download and consider to simply use ' var clouddb = require(./js/poucdb.min.js)' instead of working with the NPM approach.  Though i'm not sure if this will not suffer in terms of performance.  I'm not sure what you mean with TabrisJS style. I've done just that as far as i know. Then i run 'cordova run android' or 'cordova build android' which returns the error when i installed pouchdb using npm, this install 55MB instead of 54kb or so.  I appreciate yr feedback.